# Copy a column and add a prefix to new column in R with dplyr

Tags: r, copy, dplyr, multiple-columns, prefix

Does someone know how to copy a column in a `data.frame` and add a prefix to the new column?

The idea is to have a character vector containing certain column names of a dataframe and to copy these with a prefix to subsequently perform an action upon.

The reason is that I want to use the spread function on these columns, but as far as I know the spread function does not preserve the original column. What I would like:

From a data.frame with the following column names:

```
column_names <- c('var1', 'var2', 'var3')
```

To a dataframe with the following columns

```
column_names <- c('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'prefix_var1','prefix_var3')
```

Where the columns with 'prefix' contain the same data as their orginal columns.

What I've tried so far, which partially succeeded:

```
sel_columns <- c('var1', 'var3')

data <- data.frame(var1 = c(12,3,4), var2 = c(123,5435,121), var3 = c(23,456,123))

new_data <- data %>% mutate_at(one_of(sel_columns), funs(.))
#Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
#  could not find function "var1"
#In addition: Warning message:
#In one_of(sel_columns) : Unknown variables: `var1`, `var3`


new_data2 <- data %>% select(one_of(sel_columns)) %>% mutate_all(funs(prefix = . * 1)) %>% c(data, .) %>% data.frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try this in `base R`

```
cbind(data, setNames(data[sel_columns], paste0("prefix_", sel_columns)))

#  var1 var2 var3 prefix_var1 prefix_var3
#1   12  123   23          12          23
#2    3 5435  456           3         456
#3    4  121  123           4         123
```

Comment: I found that it works indeed with the example I provided, however for my own example it resulted in a data.frame of two columns, one having the name 'data' and another have a name 'V2'. I found that using the c() function cbind() function it did work properly.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure what can be the issue. Can you post `dput(head(data))` so that we get the real dataset ?

Comment: if you indeed want to add a dplyr flavor : `bind_cols(data, setNames(data[sel_columns], paste0("prefix_",sel_columns)))`

Comment: @joel.wilson how could you do this if you had a list of "prefix_" values that you wanted to duplicate the columns with i.e. new_names <- c("prefix","prefix1","prefix2","prefix3")

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, paste0("prefix_", sel_columns) := mget(sel_columns)][]
#   var1 var2 var3 prefix_var1 prefix_var3
#1:   12  123   23          12          23
#2:    3 5435  456           3         456
#3:    4  121  123           4         123
```

Or with `.SDcols`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in `dplyr` you'd want to look into using the standard evaluation versions of the `dplyr` verbs.  @joel.wilson has the right idea, but if you're doing this programatically and using pipes, the SE versions are the proper way to do this.

```
data %>% 
  bind_cols(., select_(., .dots = setNames(sel_columns, sprintf("prefix_%s", sel_columns))))
```